# Написание собственной службы (Service) в Android

Tags: android, java, service

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь реализовать собственную службу, производящую некий процесс в фоновом режиме. В частности, попытался запустить пример из книги, реализующий фоновое воспроизведение аудио-файла. Разумеется, по старту (нажатие кнопки, в коде слушателя нажатия запускается служба) приложение в эмуляторе валится с стандартным сообщением

> has stopped unexpectedly. please try again (Force close) [closed]

Буду рад, если кто-нибудь приведет простейший пример со схожей задачей, с пояснениями.
Код примера, который валится.

Манифест приложения (тут всё в порядке)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.samples.servicelaunch"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".LaunchActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".PlayService"
        >
    </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Код класса Деятельности, запускающей службу PlayService:

```
package com.samples.servicelaunch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class LaunchActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button btnStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        final Button btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startService(new Intent(LaunchActivity.this,PlayService.class));
                Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "Service started.");

            }
        });
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "Service stopped.");
                stopService(new Intent(LaunchActivity.this,PlayService.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Здесь кнопка btnStart и должна по задумке запустить службу (create либо start, если уже была создана).

И, наконец, код класса, наследующего службу (Service):

```
package com.samples.servicelaunch;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PlayService extends Service {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample);
        mPlayer.setLooping(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mPlayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: DDMS логи посмотрите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Ваше приложение падает, в логах это должно быть отражено. Команда `adb logcat` покажет исключение и конкретно строку, где ошибка.

Пример создания службы по шагам с комментариями: [сервисы - это просто](http://blog.divenvrsk.org/2010/09/android.html?spref=tw).

Answer (score 0):

Набрал этот же пример из книги Голощапова - у меня всё заработало. Вы не забыли положить музыкальный файл sample.mp3 в папку raw? Создайте проект заново и скопируйте исходные коды . Если будет валится и дальше покажите содержимое LogCat (в Eclipse при отладке вы его увидите)